# Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL and junit is passed

Tags: java, tomcat, junit4, httpurlconnection

> this function is fulfilled by spring httpClient ，but the question remains ,i don't know why it will get 405 by HttpURLConnection

In this project(webservice). My server  want download a doc from other object storage server .So i use the following code to implement this function.i get 405 error when it run by RESTful visited,  **but ! I started using Junit tests successfully**!!!,i don't konw why, Hope to be answered

**original code**

```
    public class GetResource {

           private final static String  BOOTPATH = "resource/";


         public   static DocResource getDoc(String reporturl,String sign){
             ....
             String urlStr = reporturl+sign;
             URL url = new URL(urlStr);
             HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
             conn.setDoOutput(false);
             conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
             //设置超时间为3秒
             conn.setConnectTimeout(3*1000);
             //防止屏蔽程序抓取而返回403错误
             conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.104 Safari/537.36 Core/1.53.3373.400 QQBrowser/9.6.11864.400");
             conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
             conn.connect();
             //得到输入流
             InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
              ....
         }

         /**
          * 从输入流中获取字节数组
          * @param inputStream
          * @return
          * @throws IOException
          */
         private   static  byte[] readInputStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
             byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
             int len = 0;
             ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             while((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                 bos.write(buffer, 0, len);
             }
             bos.close();
             return bos.toByteArray();
         }

     }
```

**error**

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: http://pitanco-10042983.cossh.myqcloud.com/pitanco00002/2017/10/28/<phone>/112909.doc?sign=<base64sign>
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1840)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)...
```

**junit**

```
@Test
public  void m() {
    try{
        GetResource.getDoc("http://pitanco-10042983.cossh.myqcloud.com/pitanco00002/2017/10/28/<phone>/112909.doc",
                "?sign=<sign>");
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

**ps.environment**

> java 1.8.0_77 ;spring 4.3.6;spring mvc 4.3.6;junit 4:tomcat8.5

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
```

***spring code***

```
   URI uri = new URI(urlStr);
        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory schr = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
        ClientHttpRequest chr = schr.createRequest(uri, HttpMethod.GET);

        //chr.getBody().write(param.getBytes());//body中设置请求参数
        ClientHttpResponse res = chr.execute();

        InputStream inputStream = res.getBody(); //获得返回数据
        //获取自己数组
        byte[] getData = readInputStream(inputStream);
```

Comment: 405 returns when method is not allowed. Are you sure both junit and code have same request methods??

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseCode() and see if you can add this to your unit test case to make sure that you get 200 for successful ?

Comment: im sure my unit test is successful ,because the file already existed in my local,,
ps.i update my code and paste the junit code

Comment: you catch the exception in your unit test and don't call `fail` so your test runs successfully

Comment: i know my test away success , i just use it to run my function ,and in junit test ,if the http request is failed , the console also print the error message    ,but When I run this unit ,i get 200 and i can find file that need to be downloaded  in local